# Note: post data in node/express failing

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

### I've updated the question based on the comments below:

I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Client side, I send the "user" information.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/user",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "user": "John"}),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType: "json"
})
    .done(function() {
        alert( "done");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "fail");
    })
```

On the server side,

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.post('/user', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.user);
    res.end();
});
```

This results in the `console.log` correctly recording "John", but on the client side I still get a "fail" as an alert. Can't figure out why.

I'm using latest versions of node, express and jquery.

Thanks.

### Update:

This was missing:

```
res.contentType('json');
res.send({ some: JSON.stringify({response:'json'}) });
```

Comment: Have you added a body parsing middleware like the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) module to your project and added it to your middleware stack (before your post route)?

Comment: Good catch. Nope, I hadn't earlier....Now, (1)... I used app.use(bodyParser()); and got some warnings (body-parser depricated), but it did end up in a console.log value of "John" correctly. But also in an alert of "fail" and that too only after I stop the server. ... (2) I used app.use(bodyParser.json());, as used by express-generator, and instead of "John", I get "undefined" in the console.log

Comment: I think you are not doing `res.end` that's why it's failing after timeout.

Comment: Thanks. I did res.end() and it works, resulting in "done". Please advise what do I use ? `app.use(bodyParser());` which works, giving off "deprecated" warnings or `app.use(bodyParser.json());` which doesn't work in the above case ?

Comment: If you only need to parse data which comes from `form` elements (ie. content with a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type), you should use `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`. `app.use(bodyParser())` is the "old" syntax, before bodyParser was "divided" into bodyParser.json and bodyParser.urlencoded.
Unless you specifically want your content to be sent with a `application/json` content-type, I would remove the `contentType : 'application/json'` from your AJAX call. But if that's the case, then you should use `app.use(bodyParser.json())`. Hope that helps.